# what is effected when running - hadoop namenode -format

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

we have amabri cluster ( version 2.6 ) with 24 workers machines

we want to run following commands only on worker23 machine ( because problem on worker23 ) , dose these commands effected on all FileSystem of all the workers? or only on worker23 ?

```
 $ hadoop namenode -format

 $ hdfs namenode -format
```

Answer (score 1):

You will format your entire cluster.. So I wouldn't do that unless you want to clear out the cluster.

You can just clear your your hdfs directories on that host and restart the datanode. If you have a replication set for your data you are ok

Comment: great so how to clear hdfs directories only on host worker23 ?

Comment: stop the datanode on that server and delete your hdfs directory(s) then start datanode

Comment: we get the errors - ERROR datanode.DataNode (BPServiceActor.java:run(772)) - Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid f8a931c8-b4fe-4451-9823-2308c2d693ed) , after we removed the hdfs and start the datanode

Comment: you need to remove the data dir in the hdfs dir(s)

Comment: what you mean data is under hdfs and we removed the hdfs folder

Comment: yes.. just re-create the folder structure from looking at another node and start the datanode

Comment: do you mean to do - rm -rf hadoop , and then mkdir -p hadoop/hdfs/data and then start the dadanode ?

Comment: I do it on all partitions -  rm -rf hadoop , and then mkdir -p hadoop/hdfs/data and then start the dadanode  , but still with te same problem

Comment: I get the error - 2017-11-20 21:43:30,911 ERROR datanode.DataNode (BPServiceActor.java:run(772)) - Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid ad0af75b-e973-475b-b525-52974df91fd1) service to master03

Comment: Being a complete hadoop newbie I assume this will not format my hard drive at all, but just create a hadoop file?

Comment: @Superdooperhero it just formats the journal data for HDFS